# Trouble Copying Data into File Geodatabase from Personal Geodatabase

Tags: esri-geodatabase, convert, file-geodatabase, personal-geodatabase, migration

I've been unable to successfully copy and paste personal geodatabase feature classes to a new file geodatabase in ArcCatalog 10.1. As the screenshot shows, the Data Transfer dialog box contains all the feature classes to be copied: [image: Data Transfer Dialog Box]

After clicking OK, the following error is generated:[image: One of more objects failed to paste.].

I've experimented with copying/pasting only one file at a time, and the same error continues to appear. Has anybody encountered this error when trying to paste feature classes from a personal geodatabase into a file geodatabase? If so, what steps did you take to troubleshoot it?

Thanks!

Comment: copy the entire database and then discard the items (feature classes) you do not require.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply--unfortunately all of the items within the database are relevant to my project. Do you know if there are any additional steps I need to take before trying to copy the data?

Comment: What happens if you use the tools Copy Features or Featureclass to Featureclass to transfer the files?

Comment: Using the Feature Class to Feature Class tool on a single feature class resulted in Error 00210 "Cannot Create Output".The Feature Class to Geodatabase tool also failed to execute and resulted in Error 00210. The Copy tool failed to execute as well.

Comment: does it work for a shapefile ? can you do it with data > export data ? Have you tried a "repair geometry" before copying ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have hit a data corruption issue as detailed in [Esri technical article 41119](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/41119/?wt.mc_id=emailcampaign15945). The error message matches. A file geodatabase may become corrupted that is on a remote Win7 or certain Windows Server boxes.

The problem is caused by one of several Microsoft updates and has a patch. Excerpted from the article:

> The update for KB 2732673 has been released as of August 13, 2013. The
>   hotfix is available under Microsoft Knowledge Base article 2732673.
>
> • If KB 2775511 has already been installed, install the update patch
>   found at Knowledge Base article 2732673.
>
> • If KB 2775511 is to be installed at some future date, install the 
>   2732673 update patch now to mitigate any issues that may impact file 
>   geodatabases and shapefiles stored on network drives.

Comment: mkennedy, thanks for the link to the Esri technical article! I was able to use this information to find a work-around, and simply performed the operation locally instead of on the network (a deceptively simple solution). However, if this process hadn't worked, I'm sure the IT department would have found this article very helpful as well. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "Append" (Data Management) tool?
I've found this tool useful for adding additional datasets to a File GDB.

If you chose "Schema Type NO_TEST", you get to specify which fields from the old file are imported into the new file.

Hope this helps.
thanks,
Scott B.